# Is it possible to create an Azure Service Principal with the Pulumi?

Tags: python, azure, pulumi

I have a Pulumi Python code that creates some Azure resources. Insted of I user User Account to create resource, I created an Azure Service Principal with Powershell and authenticate with the below method:

```
pulumi config set azure-native:clientId <clientID>
pulumi config set azure-native:clientSecret <clientSecret> --secret
pulumi config set azure-native:tenantId <tenantID>
pulumi config set azure-native:subscriptionId <subscriptionID>
```

Now, I want to know Is it possible to create an Azure Service Principal with Pulumi and after that authenticate with Service Principal has been created?
Other Question, Is it the true way?

**Edit:**
As these documents [Service Principal](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azuread/serviceprincipal/)
My code is:

```
import pulumi
from pulumi.output import Output
import pulumi_azure_native as azure_native
import pulumi_azuread as azuread
    
current = azuread.get_client_config()
example_application = azuread.Application("exampleApplication",
                                          display_name="example",
                                          owners=[current.object_id])
example_service_principal = azuread.ServicePrincipal("exampleServicePrincipal",
                                                     application_id=example_application.application_id,
                                                     app_role_assignment_required=False,
                                                     owners=[current.object_id])
```

I received this error. Also I install with `pip install pulumi-azuread`

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pulumi_azuread'
```

Comment: You will need to install the module with this name - `pip install pulumi_azuread`. Notice the underscore `_`, instead of a dash.

Comment: @sushant and @Piers Karsenbarg I try both of them but I received the same error. The output of `Pip freeze` is `pulumi-azuread==5.5.0`. Also, I uninstalled `pip install pulumi-azuread` and install again `pip install pulumi_azuread` but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can, using the [Service Principal resource](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azuread/serviceprincipal/) as part of the [Azure Active Directory Provider](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azuread/).

You'll need to define an application first, but in typescript it would look something like:

```js
import * as azuread from "@pulumi/azuread";

const application = new azuread.Application(`application`, {
      displayName: `application`,
});

const servicePrincipal = new azuread.ServicePrincipal(`servicePrincipal`, {
      applicationId: application.applicationId,
});
```

Comment: I received this error. Also, I install that with the below command. Is it Azure Native?
`pip install pulumi-azuread`

Error:
`import pulumi_azuread as azuread`
 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pulumi_azuread'
 `error: an unhandled error occurred: Program exited with non-zero exit code: 1`

Comment: As @sushant wrote in the comment under your question it's `pip install pulumi_azuread` with an underscore rather than a hyphen